# Stored procedure causing 100% CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in a large database. It takes 15 min and is causing 100% CPU usage. I think the reason for this is using a Cursor. How can I improve Cursor  performance, or will any alternative loop give me better performance?

```
 NextStore:
 Set @oldrn = 0  Set @OldCost = 0 Set @totalqty = 0 Set @OldDetailid = 0 set @MCOUNTER = 0Set @itemType = 0  Set @TotQty4Equation = 0 

Declare CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance  cursor   local static read_only forward_only 
          For

        SELECT  MQTY,TotalQTY,
                Price ,
                Code ,
                Entry_Date,
                ID  ,Transaction_move,FinishedReceipt_dID,Parent_ID , Final_conv
        From #AVG_WithoutBalanceTB 
        order by Entry_Date

     SET @MCOUNTER = 0
     OPEN CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance 
    Fetch Next From CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance Into @Mqty, @totalqty,@MPRICE, @Transaction_Code,@Entry_Date,@detailID ,@Transaction_move,@FinishedProductID,@parentID,@Finalconv
    While @@Fetch_Status = 0 Begin 

        Set @TotQty4Equation = @totalqty - @MQTY 
        IF @totalqty > 0 
            SET @LD_COSTPRICE= ((@MQTY*@MPRICE)+((@TotQty4Equation )*@oldcost) )/@totalqty       
        ELSE
        Begin
            IF @totalqty = 0 Set @LD_COSTPRICE = @MPRICE
            ELSE  
            SET @LD_COSTPRICE=@oldcost 
        END

        IF @LD_COSTPRICE IS NULL or @LD_COSTPRICE < 0  SET @LD_COSTPRICE = 0 
        Set @oldcost = @LD_COSTPRICE 
        update       Inv_Receipt_d set  AvgCost = @oldcost   where id = @Detailid



        NextLoop:    


    Fetch Next From CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance Into @Mqty,@totalqty,@MPRICE, @Transaction_Code,@Entry_Date,@detailID ,@Transaction_move,@FinishedProductID,@parentID,@Finalconv

    End     

    Close CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance
    Deallocate CUR_AdjustAVGWithoutBalance
    Drop table #AVG_WithoutBalanceTB ;   

    While @readrownum <= @insertrownum
    Begin

        Select @STORE_id = transStore ,@AT_DATE =  transdate ,@detailID = TransDetailID  from @TransferTrans where rownum = @readrownum ;
        Set @readrownum = @readrownum + 1
        GoTo NextStore
    END
```

Comment: Why are you using a `CURSOR` here? SQL is a *set-based* language. What is your actual goal here? What you have heavily reads like a Programming language, which SQL is not.

Comment: Rewrite this to use CASE statements rather than the cursor.  It will run much, much more quickly.

Comment: `CASE` **expression** @RobertSievers . `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: this sql code update about 2 million record in C# it take very long time

Comment: That last loop seems odd and the variables it uses are not defined in your script. In addition, whenever I see "GOTO" used in any language I get very suspicious of the logic. You also have a label "NextLoop" which isn't referenced anywhere - so I suspect you need to revisit all of the logic in the procedure. It is scary to think that your code would jump into the middle of your cursor loop from somewhere outside that cursor logic. Lastly, if you going to use terminators (and you should), you should do so consistently.

Comment: hello SMor i update the code to view  NextStore: